# Struggling with where to declare a variable in a very basic Javascript game

Tags: javascript, variables, methods

I've been doing a basic Pluralsight Javascript course at the end of which I need to make a simple text based game using:

```
confirm()
prompt()
alert()
If/else
math.round()
math.random()
Operators like === etc.
```

I've come up with a scenario (this is what I'm trying to achieve) in which the player is confronted by the wolf, and via a prompt() has the choice to **chat**, **attack** or **run**, and a rounded random number is generated in the background.  Depending on what is returned in the prompt, the below will run:

a) If the response is **run**, then a confirm() window popups up asking if the player is sure they want to do that.

- If the value returned is true and the random number equals 0, then the player is alerted he gets away (survives).
- If the value returned is true but the random number equals q, the player gets alerted that he dies (eaten by the wolf).

  - If the value is false, the player is alerted that he dies.

b) If the response to the prompt is **attack** then the player is alerted he survives.

c) If the response is **chat**, the player is alerted that he dies.

d) if the response is **something else**, he is alerted that he dies.

My issue is that how to structure the code.  I understand it is good practice to declare all of my variables at the beginning of my script.  But how do I declare this:

```
var response = confirm ("Are you sure you want to do that? It's risky");
```

but not run it at that time (I only want to run it if the player returns 'run').

My question may be more clear you look at my code post my code below. Please help!

```
alert("You're off to see Grandma and you're wandering through a deep dark  forest. Suddenly you feel hot breath on the back of your neck and smell the unmistakeable stench of canine.  You turn around - it's the wolf!");  
var choice = prompt("His piercing red eyes stare through you.  He steps closer.  What do you do - chat, attack or run?");
var randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random());
//The line below I only want to run if "run" is the value returned on the prompt() above.
var response = confirm ("Are you sure you want to do that? It's risky"); 

if (choice === run)
    if (response === true && randomNumber === 0){
    alert("Wow - you made it to Grandma's.  Well done - you're safe!");
    }
    else if (response === true && randomNumber === 1){
    alert("Oh - too bad!  You couldn't out run the wolf - he catches you and eats you!")
    }
    else{
    alert("Oh no - indecisive! While you're standing there trying to choose what to do, the wolf pounces and - BAM!  You're dinner.");  
    }}

else if (choice === attack){
    alert("Brave move - you hit the wolf over the head with a stick and run to Grandma's. You're out of trouble!")
    }

else if (choice === chat){
    alert("The wolf invites you in for a cup of tea and some biscuits.  After a nice chat about the weather, he eat you.  Bad move.")
    }

else {
    alert("You choose to" + " " + choice + "?" + " " + "- what fairytale are you in? Weird.  The wolf eats you.  You're dead.")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`confirm()` is a function, so it runs and returns a value to `response` as soon as it appears. In this case, it appears *before* the key conditional statement you've written to respond to the player's input.

Since you want the confirmation dialog to appear only if the player chooses the "run" option, your call to that function should appear at that point. In your case that basically means just moving it down to just below the `if (choice === run)` line so that it comes *after* you know the player has decided to run but *before* you know the result of the confirmation dialog.

One thing to be careful about - the variable `choice` will be a String because that's what `prompt()` returns as. So when you check for equivalence in your conditional with `===` make sure that the right hand side of the operator is also a String. This means that you probably mean to write `(choice === "run")` instead of `(choice === run)` for example. Otherwise when the computer sees `(choice === run)` in your code, it's going to look at `run` and think you're talking about a *variable* named `run` and not the *word* run. It would only work if you had declared `var run = "run"` somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have to initialize your variables with anything.

So you can do this:

```
var response, choice, randomNumber;

randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random());

// introduce the game
alert("You're off to see Grandma and you're wandering through a deep dark  forest. Suddenly you feel hot breath on the back of your neck and smell the unmistakeable stench of canine.  You turn around - it's the wolf!");

// first player choice
choice = prompt("His piercing red eyes stare through you.  He steps closer.  What do you do - chat, attack or run?");

// game logic
if (choice === 'run') {
  response = confirm ("Are you sure you want to do that? It's risky");

  if (response === true && randomNumber === 0){
    alert("Wow - you made it to Grandma's.  Well done - you're safe!");
  }

  // the rest of your code as-is
}
```

Another couple of points:

You most likely want to check that `choice` is a particular string.  Strings must be enclosed in quotes, otherwise it's considered a variable.

So `if (choice === run)` should be changed to `if (choice === 'run')`.

Another point is you can use a switch statement (It's not required and the way you are doing it perfectly fine, just thought I'd present other options to you), like this:

```
switch (choice) {
  case 'run':
    // code to handle run
    break;

  case 'attack':
    // code to handle break
    break;

  case 'chat':
    // code to handle chat
    break;
}
```

Comment: That's great - thanks heaps.  Good points.  I hadn't picked up on the string thing regarding "run".  I'm getting into switch statements now, so that makes sense.